# Show div based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this menu: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EPvGf/52/
 and I would like to make something like this:

> If url contains eg. #div3 than page will open on "Returns" and "Third Div".

Js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();
$('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
    $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
    // fade out all open subcontents
    $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
    // fade in new selected subcontent
    $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
});});
```

Comment: Did you solve it already?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the fragment from the URL using `window.location.hash`. If you extract the logic which hides/shows the relevant div from the link to its own function, you can then run it on load too. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();

    // on click
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        showDiv($(this).data('id'));
    });

    // on load
    if (window.location.hash)
        showDiv(window.location.hash);

    function showDiv(id) {
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        $('.pbox[id=' + id + ']').show(600);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/331/)

Comment: Ok, i think we are close, but if url is eg #div3, then "Third div" is hidden